# Clone a container in extjs

Tags: javascript, extjs, containers

When I click a add button it needs to add a same container again. The below I have given my code segment

```
var rulepanel = Ext.apply(me, {
    items: [{
        xtype: 'uxform',
        id: 'rule',
        bodyPadding: 10,

        items: [{
            xtype: 'container',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'match',
                name: 'name',
                allowBlank: false,
                placeholder: 'match'
            }]
        }, {
            xtype: 'container',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                fieldLabel: 'Product/KPI',
                name: 'name',
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                id: 'add',
                text: 'Add',
                handler: function(button, event) {
                    //rulepanel.insert(0, Ext.create(rulepanel.model)); 
                    // so here how can I add it
                }
            }],
        }]
    }]
});
```

So when click the add button what I need is I need to clone the "match,product/kpi and add button" fields. How can I achieve this task. I have tried with cloneconfig(). But couldn't achieve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: it would be good it you create some fiddle

Comment: You can move the part that should be duplicated into its own `Ext.define` block, thus making it clearly reusable. Then you can easily create multiple instances of this using `Ext.create`

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJs, You create your own component as common and you can reuse whenever you required in application. You need to use [`Ext.define`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.0/#!/api/Ext-method-define)

> Defines a class or override. A basic class is defined like this:

```
Ext.define('My.awesome.Class', {
     someProperty: 'something',

     someMethod: function() {
         alert(s + this.someProperty);
     }

     ...
 });

 var obj = new My.awesome.Class();

 obj.someMethod('Say '); // alerts 'Say something'
```

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2got)**, I have created a demo using your code as reference. Hope this will help/guide you to achieve your requirement.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {
        Ext.define('ProductKpi', {
            extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
            xtype: 'productkpi',
            layout: {
                type: 'hbox',
                align: 'stretch'
            },
            margin:5,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'combobox',
                flex:1,
                fieldLabel: 'Product/KPI',
                name: 'name',
            }, {
                xtype: 'button',
                margin:'0 5',
                text: 'Add',
                handler: function (button, event) {
                    button.up('#rule').add({
                        xtype: 'productkpi'
                    })
                }
            }],
        });
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Demo',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            id: 'rule',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'container',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    fieldLabel: 'match',
                    name: 'name',
                    allowBlank: false,
                    placeholder: 'match'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'productkpi'
            }]
        });
    }
});
```